# Вывести элемент записанный в виде строковой переменной на страницу

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Хочу собрать элемент/набор элементов в виде строковой переменной и вывести все это дело на страницу.

```
 Пример элемента:

    elem = '<button>'+'abc'+'</button>'
```

Пробовал выводить это через `.textContent=elem` и `.append(elem)`, но почему-то js это воспринимает, не, как элемент, а просто как строку. Вот так вот это выглядит->
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно реализовать эту идею?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `textContent` -> `innerHTML`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсказали с решением - использовать вместо `textContent` это-> `innerHtml`

Comment: А почему `innerHTML`, а не `textContent`?

Comment: Потому что `textContent`  не работает, в самом вопросе написано

Answer (score 0):

```js
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = 'abc';
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
myDiv.appendChild(button);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Хочу собрать элемент/набор элементов в виде строковой переменной и вывести все это дело на страницу.

Есть метод `insertAdjacentHTML`. Имеет хорошее количество возможностей...

```js
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<p>Привет</p>');
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>Я тут</p>');
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p>Пока</p>');
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Более подробнее про преобразовании ДОМ можно прочитать в учебнике. https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document